# Add Avatar to Material-UI AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add an Avatar to an AppBar. However, the Avatar is not getting added to the  AppBar. Could you please assist me. Please refer the attached image for my coding[image]

Comment: Which version of Material-UI are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V1+ documentation : https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/

V0+ documentation : https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

The property "iconElementRight" is only available on v0+

If you migrated to the V1 you have to add the icon yourself as a child of the AppBar.